# Explanations on the proof that the sequence $b_k={\tbinom {n}{k}}$ is increasing on $0\le k\le\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ et $f_n$ is a function defined by  :
>   $${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}f_n\colon [|0,n|] &\longrightarrow \mathbb {N} \\k&\longmapsto {\displaystyle {\tbinom {n}{k}}}\end{aligned}}} $$
>   Show that $f_n$ is increasing on $\left [\left|0,\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}{2} \rfloor \right|\right]$

I don't understand the following proof :

- why the author took $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and not in $\left [\left|0,n \rfloor \right|\right]$ because if $k\in \mathbb{N}$ we could be have $k>n$ then $f_{n}(k)=0$ vanished so the expression $\dfrac{f_{n}(k+1)}{f_{n}(k)}$ will have no sense
- what is the reason that let author deduced from 
  $$f_n\left(\lfloor \dfrac{n-1}{2} \rfloor \right)\leq f_n\left(\lfloor \dfrac{n+1}{2} \rfloor \right) $$
  that $f_{n}$ is increasing on $\left [\left|0,\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}{2} \rfloor \right|\right]$

**Update:**
Is the following remark true ?

> To show that a map $f$ is increasing on $[|n,n + p|]$ where $n$ is an integer and $p$ a non-zero natural integer, it suffices to show that $f(k)\leq f(k +1)$ All $k$ between $n$ and $n+p-1$.

[image]

Comment: OK, the writing is sloppy but is there any step in this, whose corrected version is not crystal clear?

Comment: yes i pointed out  in second bullet.

Comment: The trouble is that nowhere did the author deduce from what you say that the whole sequence is increasing...

Comment: so is it just as said Misha "extra care to make sure that at the highest value we consider, $k = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor,$ the inequality $k \le \frac{n-1}{2}$ still holds,"  ? else could you elaborate

Comment: Yes, @Misha's answer is spot on (but why do you have to ask for confirmations when all there is to do is to compare this answer to the text you quote?).

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the ratio $\frac{f_n(k+1)}{f_n(k)}$ should have been considered for $k \in [\![0,n-1]\!]$ and not for all $k \in \mathbb N,$ for exactly the reasons you point out, so let's just pretend that the proof does that instead.

The proof actually considers all $k$ in that interval, though, not just $k = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor.$ The argument runs: since $\frac{f_n(k+1)}{f_n(k)} = \frac{n-k}{k+1},$ we have $$f_n(k+1) \ge f_n(k) \iff \frac{f_n(k+1)}{f_n(k)} \ge 1 \iff \frac{n-k}{k+1} \ge 1,$$ and the final inequality simplifies to $k \le \frac{n-1}{2}.$ The author of the proof just wants to take extra care to make sure that at the highest value we consider, $k = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor,$ the inequality $k \le \frac{n-1}{2}$ still holds, I guess?

Comment: Much better than the textbook, which takes about a whole page for what should be at most 2 lines.

Comment: Could you say something about my remark it's true ?

Comment: The remark is not true for functions that take a real number as input, but in this problem, $f$ takes an integer as input, so by comparing $f(k)$ to $f(k+1)$ for all $k$, we've considered all cases